# ngOnChanges tracking previous value and new value?

Tags: angular

In my angular project, I'm trying to be able to go through a list by hitting next/previous buttons. I have a checkbox that changes the hours displayed from hours to days. I want to be able to go back and forth through the employees and have the values be correct. I'm told that this can be done through ngOnChanges and tracking the previous and new value.

This is what I have, which is changing the new value, but how would I change the previous value?

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: { [propName: string]: SimpleChange }) {
    for (let propName in changes) {
        if (propName == "selectedEmployee") {
            if (this.timeVar == "days") {
                this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].STDLTD = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].STDLTD * 8;
                this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].Uncharged = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].Uncharged * 8;

                this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTOBase = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTOBase * 8;
                this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTOCarry = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTOCarry * 8;
                this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTOBorrowed = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTOBorrowed * 8;
                this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTOBalance = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTOBalance * 8;
                this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTORequests = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTORequests * 8;
                this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTORemaining = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTORemaining * 8;

                this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].ETOEarned = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].ETOEarned * 8;
                this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].ETORequests = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].ETORequests * 8;
                this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].ETORemaining = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].ETORemaining * 8;  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the question is not very clear... why can't you simply use an index to navigate the items of the array/list?

Comment: I am using an index, which is the selectedEmployee. The problem isn't navigating through the array, it's that whenever I have the time converted from hours to days, and then go to the next person, it's displayed in hours but says days.

Comment: sorry, it's just a confusing question/problem. I've tried explaining it as best as I can @crash

Comment: Probably it would be better if you can update your question with the rest of the code. I can't see why you need to use `ngOnChanges` to achieve this apparently simple task. Also, afaik, `ngOnChanges` will also be triggered a huge amount of times and its use should be limited

Comment: @crash basically, what I'm asking is, since ngOnChanges can take in the previous and current values, how do I access the previous value?

Comment: I answered below, have a look at it and let me know if it's what you're looking for

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges):

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  for (let propName in changes) {
    let chng = changes[propName];
    let cur  = JSON.stringify(chng.currentValue);
    let prev = JSON.stringify(chng.previousValue);
  }
}
```

So, you'll need the `.currentValue` and `.previousValue` property to access current and previous values.

Comment: I get a Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify!!!, any ideas

Comment: There is no need to JSON.stringify.

Answer (score 1):

A safer way to use ngOnChanges:

*nameof.ts*

```
export const nameof = <T>(name: keyof T) => name;
```

*my.component.ts*

```js
selectedEmployee: string[];

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    // won't compile if 'selectedEmployee' is no a property of this component
    const change = changes[nameof<MyComponent>('selectedEmployee')];

    if (change) {
      // casting it, to avoid dumb error that won't throw, like
      // doing `change.currentValue > 0` instead of `change.currentValue.length > 0`
      const previous: string[] = change.previousValue;
      const current: string[] = change.currentValue;

      // do something with it.
    }
  }
```